# How to change the image when an inline button is pressed?

Tags: telegram-bot

I am trying to make my Telegram bot change the image when an inline button is pressed in the message. Can you help me with this? I cannot find a tutorial on this topic.

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher
from main import bot
from database.pictures import im1, im2, im3
import aiogram.types as types

images = [im1, im2, im3]

current_image = 0
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def cmd_photo(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='←', callback_data='left'),
                 types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='→', callback_data='right'))
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=images[current_image], reply_markup=keyboard)

async def change_image_callback_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    global current_image
    if query.data == 'left':
        current_image = (current_image - 1) % len(images)
    elif query.data == 'right':
        current_image = (current_image + 1) % len(images)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='←', callback_data='left'),
                 types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='→', callback_data='right'))
    await query.message.edit_media(media=types.InputMediaPhoto(media=images[current_image]), reply_markup=keyboard)

def register_handlers_change_photo(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cmd_photo, commands="Фото")
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(change_image_callback_handler)
```

The image with the inline buttons appears, but it does not change.

Comment: please add tags, especially for the language that is used. I would have done it, but I don’t recognize the language.

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/edit_message_media.html